# Как выделять области на Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, карты

Как можно в Google Maps сделать такие же полигоны, как на [этой карте](http://linkit.lv/ru/pokritie)?

Answer (score 1):

Это всего лишь пользовательская  карта Google. Открываете раздел "Мои карты", создаете там новую карту. Среди инструментов есть полигон. Тщательно и кропотливо повторяете границы районов на карте.

Обратите внимание, что при большом увеличении заметны несоответствия полигонов и границ на карте. Т.е. полигоны созданы вручную.